# SQL not returning expected results

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

When I enter this piece of SQL into PHPMyAdmin it returns results that don't match what I am expecting

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `wtlaptop`
WHERE
    `laptopgpu` LIKE '%GTX%'
    OR
    `laptopgpu` LIKE '%RTX%'
    AND
    `memorysize` LIKE '%16GB%'
    OR
    `memorysize` LIKE '%32GB%'
    OR
    `memorysize` LIKE '%64GB%'
    AND
    `laptopbrand` LIKE '%Asu%'
ORDER BY
    ABS(`productprice` - 3145)
```

My Intent is to find the laptops that have either a GTX GPU or an RTX GPU with 16GB or 32GB of ram made by ASUS and then order it so from the closest to the user inputted price.

However, when I run this query in PHPMyAdmin I get results that have 8GB of ram and results that are not from brands such as ASUS.
Example

```
3128
Intel Core i7
32GB
Nvidia GTX 1650 Ti
Windows 10 Home
HP
```

My Table structure is

```
productprice varchar(61),
cpufamily    varchar(25),
memorysize   varchar(20),
laptopgpu    varchar(28),
laptopos     varchar(32),
laptopbrand  varchar(9)
```

Comment: Data-quality is a huge problem with retail products databases - are you sure that none of the entries in `memorysize` contain spaces or different units? e.g. `'32'` vs `'32 GB'` vs `'32GB'` vs `'32768MB'`? I strongly suggest you normalize your data first when you import it so you can use strongly-typed columns to avoid problems like these (so `memorysize` is `int` in megabytes instead of `varchar`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify what you expect, but I think you just need parens around your conditions:

```
SELECT *
FROM `wtlaptop`
WHERE (`laptopgpu` LIKE '%GTX%' OR `laptopgpu` LIKE '%RTX%') AND 
      (`memorysize` LIKE '%16GB%' OR `memorysize` LIKE '%32GB%' OR `memorysize` LIKE '%64GB%') AND
      `laptopbrand` LIKE '%Asu%'
ORDER BY ABS(`productprice` - 3145);
```

You can also simplify this using regular expressions:

```
SELECT *
FROM `wtlaptop`
WHERE `laptopgpu` REGEXP 'GTX|RTX' AND
      `memorysize` REGEXP '16GB|32GB|64GB' AND
      `laptopbrand` LIKE '%Asu%'
ORDER BY ABS(`productprice` - 3145);
```